# Cant get GPIO input working

Tags: gpio

I have my Pi set up using a [Powered USB Hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Z4G3I6). I have followed all the directions to create a mini arcade following the [Adafruit tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/retro-gaming-with-raspberry-pi/buttons). But none of the controls on the right side of the board work. (GPIO 23,25,7)

At first I thought maybe the pins didn't work so I set every pin to output using

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setup( xx , GPIO.OUT )
GPIO.output( xx , GPIO.HIGH )
```

And had an LED connected to ground and tested that every GPIO could light it up. It was successful, so all the pins work fine.

So i assumed maybe it was the controls. I put power on one side of the control & a grounded LED on the other side. Upon using the control (pressing button) the LED would light up, so its not the control.

So its not the GPIO & its not the controls. All the controls with issues are on the same side of my bread board so now I'm guessing its a power issue?  What should I do?

*I have also tried switching which pins are used, the issue persisted*

Comment: Do you have some sort of circuit diagram for how things are connected? I'm confused as to what you're trying to do and what the expected outcome is so I'm finding it hard to work out what the problem could be.

Comment: Have you considered that the breadboard or jumpers maybe bad (especially since all the problems are on one side)?

Answer (score -2):

You would have to use GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) in order to get it working.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. While we're glad you're trying to help out, the OP said that it's not the controls (code), so this answer isn't all that helpful.